# Блок игнорирует заданную ширину

Tags: css

```css
.container__flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.beoplay {
  max-width: 560px;
  min-height: 520px;
  background-image: url("../images/Beoplay A1 product.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

.beoplay__heading {
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.beoplay__text {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.beoplay__button {
  font-size: 18px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 13px 38px 7px 38px;
}

.leica {
  max-width: 560px;
  min-height: 520px;
  background-image: url("../images/Leica MP product.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__flex">
  <section class="beoplay">
    <h1 class="heading beoplay__heading">BEOPLAY A1</h1>
    <p class="text beoplay__text">The ultra-portable Bluetooth speaker that will travel with you anywhere</p>
    <a href="" class="button beoplay__button">Buy</a>
  </section>

  <section class="leica">
    <h1 class="heading leica__heading">Leica MP</h1>
    <p class="text leica__text">Focused technology for focused photography</p>
    <a href="" class="button leica__button">Buy</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

Почему ширина блока не принимает ширину, заданную в свойстве `width`?

Answer (score 0):

CSS-свойство `width` задаёт не общую ширину блока, а только ширину содержания. Общая ширина блока затем складывается из трёх компонентов: ширины содержания, внутренних отступов и ширины рамок слева и справа.

Если вы хотите, чтобы свойство width включало в себя также внутренние отступы, то нужно задать следующее свойство:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```